# Pass @Input as Parameters fires Type 'string' has no properties in common with type

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I am creating a dynamic tab based components and passing the necessary component properties to build the component through an object.

How to pass `@Input` as a parameter and then use the input with `ComponentFactoryResolver` and create inputs.

Here is the object to hold the necessary Tab Component Properties,

Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-as-params)

**tab-item.ts**

```
import { Type, Input } from '@angular/core';

export class TabItem {

    componentLoaded = false;

    constructor(public title: string, public active: boolean, public component: Type<object>, public inputs: Input[] = []) {

    }
}
```

**tab-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentFactory, Injector, ApplicationRef, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { TabItem } from 'src/app/models/tab-item';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tab',
    template: `
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                   <ul class="nav flex-column">
                      <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let tab of tabItems">
                         <a class="nav-link" (click)="setActiveTabItem(tab)" [class.active]="tab.active" [id]="tab.title+'-tab'"
                           data-toggle="tab" [href]="'#' + tab.title" role="tab" [attr.aria-controls]="tab.title"
                           aria-selected="true">{{tab.title}}</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
             <div class="col-10">
                <div id="tab-container" class="tab-content">
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./tab.component.scss']
})
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() tabItems: TabItem[];
    componentsCreated: ComponentFactory<object>[] = [];

    constructor(private componentFactorResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private injector: Injector,
                private app: ApplicationRef,
                private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    loadTabContent(selectedIndex: number, isHome: boolean = false): void {
        const tabItem = this.tabItems[selectedIndex];
        const componentFactory = 
        this.componentFactorResolver.resolveComponentFactory(tabItem.component);

        // Assign Inputs
        if (tabItem.inputs) {
            tabItem.inputs.forEach((item: Input) => {
                 componentFactory.inputs.push(item);
            });
        }

        const newNode = document.createElement('div');
        newNode.id = tabItem.title;
        document.getElementById('tab-container').appendChild(newNode);

        const ref = componentFactory.create(this.injector, [], newNode);
        this.app.attachView(ref.hostView);
    }
}
```

Here, in the above code, I am getting the below error with `componentFactory.inputs.push(item);`

> Argument of type 'Input' is not assignable to parameter of type '{
> propName: string; templateName: string; }'.
>
> Type 'Input' is missing the following properties from type '{
> propName: string; templateName: string; }': propName,
> templateNamets(2345)

Finally, Creating tab items like below and passing it from the parent component

```
<app-tab [tabItems]="tabItems"></app-tab>


@Input() header = 'Test';
tabItems = [
            new TabItem('Home', true, HomeComponent),
            new TabItem('Profile', false, ProfileComponent),
            new TabItem('Employee', false,  EmployeeComponent, [this.header])
        ];
```

Here, the error is,

> Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'Input'.ts(2559)

Is this is the right way to pass inputs? If so, what's wrong with this?

Comment: create a fiddle for your question in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: added the fiddle

Comment: Close voter. The answer you suggested is completely different from this. Please read the question and code carefully before voting for close. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it to work with the below changes. **Still looking for the best approach if any.**

Used rest operator for arguments without specifying the `Input` type

```
import { Type, Input } from '@angular/core';

export class TabItem {

    componentLoaded = false;
    args;

    constructor(public title: string, public active: boolean, public component: Type<object>, ...args) {

    }
}
```

**tab-component.ts**

```
loadTabContent(selectedIndex: number, isHome: boolean = false): void {
    const tabItem = this.tabItems[selectedIndex];
    const componentFactory = 
    this.componentFactorResolver.resolveComponentFactory(tabItem.component);

    const newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.id = tabItem.title;
    document.getElementById('tab-container').appendChild(newNode);

    const ref = componentFactory.create(this.injector, [], newNode);
    this.app.attachView(ref.hostView);

    if (tabItem.args) {
        tabItem.args.forEach((item) => {
             Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
                 const value = item[key];
                 
                 ref.instance[key] = value; //Here it works!
             });
        });
    }

}
```

When created, here it is no need to be of `Input` type and just a `key:value` pair would suffice

```
<app-tab [tabItems]="tabItems"></app-tab>

tabItems = [
            new TabItem('Home', true, HomeComponent),
            new TabItem('Employee', false,  EmployeeComponent, {'header': 'Test data'})
        ];
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [`ComponentFactory` docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory) it has an [`inputs` property](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory#inputs) which expects `Array` of `{ propName: string; templateName: string; }`.

Your problem comes from 2 violations :

1. Inside *app.component.ts* where you try to consider `@Input`
   directive as `Input` type while you set it as `string`!
2. Inside *tab.component.ts* where you are trying to push an `Input` as
   type of  `ComponentFactory`'s `inputs`!

My changes in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-as-params-doblvt) may guide you to write a better code.

Comment: Which one? can you sent the last stackblitz?

Comment: I've updated the same. Even this won't work. `@Input() header: string = 'Test' as Input;` It's unnecessary casting from `sometype` to `Input`.

Comment: Also, this is a generic component. It has no meaning in explicitly casting to `Input` from wherever it is being called.

Comment: @Hary Any way, your problem changed to `'app-tab' is not a known element:` which is a module configuration error based on my changes. At least you should remove that to continue!

Comment: I've already removed it and fixed the necessary imports

Comment: @Hary I completely changed my answer.

Comment: I've already identified the problems and added an answer :) This supports only string inputs. What about others? However, I already have a working piece. Thanks!